# What does "be matched by" mean?

Tags: meaning

I found it in a Writing task 1 sample of Cambridge. Here is the full sentence:

> In contrast, France used coal as a source for only 25 units of electricity in    1980, which was matched by natural gas.

Comment: What exactly is the task?? Also, one wonders what units of electricity means.

Comment: @Lambie It's in test 4 of Cambridge Ielts 7.

Comment: You are not answering the question. What is the TASK?

Comment: What do you mean? I said it's a sentence in Writing Task 1 of test 4 in Cambridge Ielts 7.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find the sentence very clear, and would want some context. But in the absence of any better clues I would interpret "matched by" as "the same number as", with an implication that this was something that natural gas *achieved*.